# react-native-video auto repeat issue on IOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-video

I am developing react native app that show video. I have used react-native-video package. When the video page open, the video will auto start for once and should not repeat after the video end. It works well on android but on IOS the video auto start again from the beginning and keep repeating. This is my code to stop video after the video end:

```
  const onEnd = () => {
   setState({ ...state, play: false, showControls: true });
   if (videoRef.current) {
     videoRef.current.seek(0);
   }
  };
```

How I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by removing this line of my code. Keep current video time at maximum duration and don't set to 0, it will make infinite repeat condition.

```
if (videoRef.current) {
 videoRef.current.seek(0);
}
```

Comment: what if we need to seek to 0 after ending the video. how to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Create a state alongside play_pause --> 
        const [videoStarted, setVideoStarted] = useState(false);

    // update play_pause func -->
        const _handlePlayPauseClick = () => {
            // update state and call the seek function here instead 
            // of calling in the end of video.
            setVideoPaused(!videoPaused);
            setVideoStarted(true);  
            if(!videoStarted){
                _seekVideo(0)
            }
            // <---
        };

    // update video_end func -->
        const _handleEnd = () => {
            setVideoPaused(true);
            setVideoStarted(false);  // --> add it
            // _seekVideo(0);  // --> remove it
        };
    
        const _seekVideo = (timeInSeconds) => {
            if (videoRef.current) {
                videoRef.current.seek(timeInSeconds);
                setProgress(timeInSeconds);
            }
        };

   // Video component -->
            <Video
                ref={videoRef}
                source={{ uri: videoUrl }}
                resizeMode="cover"
                controls={false}
                paused={videoPaused}
                style={{
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
                    right: 0,
                }}
                onLoad={_handleLoad}
                onProgress={_handleProgress}
                onEnd={_handleEnd}
            />
```

You are good to go now. Hope this will help